# Umbraco Dialogue Theme

Tags: umbraco7

Trying to get Umbraco dialogues to work. New install on version Umbraco 7.5.4.
Running it on a local machine for testing using visual studio 2015.

I cannot see the pages when I preview them. I are putting this down to not being able to sellect a them at this stage. in the back office when I sellect my I get an error "request error url returned a 404 (not found) backoffice/propertyeditors/Getthemes"
I also get the same error for the backoffice/propertyeditors/editpermissions.

The instructions indicate that I need to copy the default folder and rename it to create my own themes. Where should it be copied to?

Comment: Are you using a third party package/theme of some sorts? A Uskinned theme perhaps? Umbraco doesn't have themes by default

Comment: Yes I know umbraco dosnt have themes. I have my own skin for my website that I have not applied to the forum. But Dialogue has a them option. default theme is found in "UmbracoCMS\App_Plugins\Dialogue\Themes\Default".

Comment: quote from instructions for Dialogue

"You should be able to integrate Dialogue into your own sites, you just need to copy the 'Default' theme folder (Including all sub folders and files) and rename it to whatever you want.

Then in the backoffice, change the 'Theme' to be your new folder. Now you can start updating the styles as you want.

Make sure you don't remove this JavaScript entry, as all the Ajax calls depend on it.

var app_base = '@Url.Content("~/")';

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Created a new project in VS2015 using MVC4 as the base.

pm install-package UmbracoCsm

setup umbraco with a new SQL database.

follow these instructions http://www.codeshare.co.uk/blog/getting-dialogue-forum-package-to-work-with-umbraco-743/

rebuild entire website last.